# Automatically calculating values for points that intersect with line

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.12.
I have two point layers and one line layer.
Each point layer consists of dots and each dot has an integer attribute value of random numbers.

The line is supposed to show a label where if the line intersects any points, it calculates and displays the sum of integer values for those points.

*note : the line should update the sum if I edit it to intersect more points with an integer value

[image]

Comment: This is easy if the numbers are random then the sum is random also, you just find a new random (sum) number with rand(x, y).

Comment: can you make the function of easier way and explain it ? please

Comment: Sorry, just a joke. I made an answer using virtual layers for a start up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sum all of the values of the intersected dots with an aggregate fuction like this one:

`aggregate( --> aggregate() function, aggregates other layer's values
layer:='point1', --> layer where the values you need are
aggregate:='sum', --> what you'll do with the values (sum of all values)
expression:="attribute", --> attribute where the values are (you have to change this)
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent) --> how to filter the values 
                                             --(if point intersects the line)
)
 + --> same function but with second layer of point
aggregate(layer:='point2',aggregate:='sum',expression:="attribute", filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))`

You can find a description of every fuction in the qgis expression builder.
The label should recalculate everytime you modify the line.

Comment: i am really new to Qgis, can you explain every function you made ?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: thank mate, your solution nearly correct, but it gives more than one label when more dots are connected, how to make it just one label ?

Comment: in addition, how to globalize this problem, for example, if i have 10000 layers of points

Comment: for one label, you should be able to check "only one label" (or something like that) in the labels paramaters. for a 10000 layers, it would be more efficient to merge them first

Comment: any other ways without merging them ? because i need it for visual purpose. Or, what if i want to know which point touching the line without defining the point layer ? can we do that ?

Comment: yes but that would be an other question I think

Comment: sounds like this ?
"Automatically calculating values for points that intersect with line without defining points layer"

Answer (score 4):

Another way is building a Virtual Layer (Data Source Manager | Virtual Layer). Here is something you can start with, one point and one line layer.

```
with linebuffer as (
    select st_buffer(geometry, 1) geometry from myline
),
pointonline as (
    select p.*
    from mypoint p
    inner join linebuffer l on st_within(p.geometry, l.geometry)
)
select sum(p.some_no), l.geometry sum
from pointonline p, myline l
```

[image]

The Virtual Layer is dynamic, so adding a point on the line, will automatically update the sum of the touching points. Since it is a problem with geometry dimensions find a point on a line, since the line has no width, I used a buffer of 1 m, making the line a polygon.

Here is how it looks in the Data Source Manager. You need to replace mypoint and myline tablenames with your own.

[image]

Comment: can you show me your attribute table for each layer ?
and please explain each line of your code, i am really new :((

Comment: I only have a column named some_no in the point table. Thats all, besides the geometry columns.

Comment: If your totally new to SQL, this might be a too advanced solution for your problem. The first block makes a one meter buffer around your line. The second block selects the points within that buffer, the third block sums the number in the some_no column of the pointtoline CTM and adds the line geometry.

Comment: i like the solution, but like you said it is too advance for me, but i will try it, thank a lot mate, i will comeback when i am stucked with the code

Comment: i tried your solution already, i change myline to my line layername, and mypoint to my points layer name. then error on "sum(p.some_no)". i tried to change it with name of field attribute but give all sum value including points which not touching the line.