# Sum every points value layer that intersect line and automatically update label sum if more points intersected

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using 3.12 QGIS version. I have got two point layers, and one line layer.

I wanna put a label on line layer, that calculate "sum" of intersected points or any mathematical calculation.

The main purpose is collecting any points (value) which intersected with line, but to keep in mind, we assume there are thousands point intersected, so when we build the code in expression dialog, we dont need to define the points layer, because generalizing the solution would be better.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically calculating values for points that intersect with line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358468/automatically-calculating-values-for-points-that-intersect-with-line)

Comment: indeed similar, but not the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregate function in the expression. I show you an example. I have a point layer 'pnt' and a line layer 'ln'. Point are not necessary the vertices of the line, those are near to the line (in my expression the limit is 20 map units).

1. Open the labelling tab for the line layer in layer styling or in layer properties.
2. Set labelling to Single Labels
3. Push the expression button on the right of the Value field
4. Enter the following expression:

   aggregate( 'pnt', 'count', 'id', contains(buffer(geometry(@parent),20), $geometry))

Explanation:

The aggregate function can collect data from other layers in the project. First you have to add the layer name or layer ID, then the name of aggregate function (there are 10+ functions), a column name the aggregate function works (in the case of count any column can be used), the last parameters is a filter. In the filter I used buffer for lines to find points very near to line (it may not need for you).

For several point layers, I suppose you can make a OGR virtual format from your point layers and add it to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: first thank you mate for the answer.
your solution counts the dots, not the attribute value inside the dots layer. besides, i prefer to count the dot only once even if thousands of line intersected there.

Comment: anyway, is there solution that doesnt require defining points layer ?

Comment: You can replace 'count' to 'sum' and 'id' to the column you would like to sum up. Your comment makes your question not clear. Update your question and tell us what you want, what you tried so far and what your real question.

Comment: i have update the description, do you get my purpose of the question ? sorry if my english is bad

Comment: You can write a Python function on the Function Editor tab of Field Calculator which you can call from your expression. In that function use a loop to  go through several layers. But for thousands of layers the on the fly sum of values won't be effective.

Comment: can u build the function for me pls ? i am so new to Qgis

Comment: No, this is a forum to answer direct questions, not for "please solve my problem".